# why error page layout not correctly applied?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

"nuxt": "^2.4.0"

my error component in layouts directory :

```
<template>
    <div class="__nuxt-error-page">
        <div class="error">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        layout: 'empty',
        name: 'error',
        props: {
            error: {
                type: Object,
                default: null
            }
        },

        computed: {
            statusCode() {
                return (this.error && this.error.statusCode) || 500
            },
            message() {
                return this.error.message || `Error`
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and empty layout :

```
<template>
    <nuxt/>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "empty",
    }
</script>
```

but when i have error , error component use another layout .. for example, when I'm on the dashboard layout  and an error occurs, error component mount on dashboard layout

<sub>*This question is available on [Nuxt](https://cmty.app/nuxt) community ([#c9154](https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c9154))*</sub>

Comment: This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512125/nuxt-js-how-to-have-separate-layout) but doesn't have an answer. It would seem to be an unresolved problem like in this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2537) which should be addressed in future releases. If you add a comment to the github issue it might help spur it along.

Comment: Create a proper bug report that is follow issue template with reproduction link